# Trouble with understanding uiviewcontrollers passing data and changing views

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Im having a bit of trouble passing some data 
(static int) between views, and I'm pretty sure its because I'm not changing view correctly, but not sure what I am doing wrong.
(and haven't used storyboards before and pretty new to this stuff)

So for instance navigating from the **Main Menu** I load **TableViewController_LevelViewTable : UITableViewController**

**TableViewController_LevelViewTable** displays all the levels of the game, When I click on a cel it should set the static int value inside the **Data** class (in relation to the level to load, and a string) later read by HelloSKScene
and then load the helloSkscene into myViewControllerToSKScene

```
if (indexPath.row ==1)
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    //Load view controller: myViewController <loads SKScene>
    myViewControllerToSKScene *tvc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerToSKScene"];
    [self.view addSubview:tvc.view];
    [self addChildViewController:tvc];

    [Data setLevel:1];
}
```

[image: CLicking on Cel 1]

This in turn loads myViewControllerToSKScene : UIViewController

```
myViewControllerToSKScene 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Create and configure the SKScene to load.
    HelloSKScene *theScene = [HelloSKScene sceneWithSize:spriteView.bounds.size];
    theScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [spriteView presentScene:theScene];
}
```

The views are loading but the data doesn’t initially but will load the second time. The is it I go from the SKScene back to menu and then return to the skscene
Somehow the static int isn’t working between the views

Also I notice that the tableview is still sitting behind the HelloSkScene view (How would I remove the tableview keeping only the SKScene onscreen, All the scenes should remove the previous scene)

With thanks
N

[image]

Below the entire storyboard I am testing embedding of tableviews, loading a tableview controller and loading a SKScene into a UIView
[image: Basic storyboard layout of project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is adding a subview to the current controller, you may want to use `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`, something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

myViewControllerToSKScene *tvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerToSKScene"];

//perhaps you want to add your level configuration here
tvc.level = indexPath.row //or just tvc.level = 1;

[self presentViewController:myViewControllerToSKScene animated:YES completition:nil];
```

More info about that in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)

You're setting the `Data` object after you create the view, that's why the first time doesn't load, but the second does, if the previous solution doesn't work for you, and you still want to use a `Data` object, you could implement something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

myViewControllerToSKScene *tvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllerToSKScene"];

[Data setLevel:1];

[self presentViewController:myViewControllerToSKScene animated:YES completition:nil];
```